# Why do Diffable Datasources treat class and struct types differently?

Tags: ios, swift, diffabledatasource

Diffable datasources require specifying a `SectionIdentifierType` and an `ItemIdentifierType` and these types have to conform to `Hashable`

Supposedly they must conform to `Hashable` so that the datasource can do its diffing.

So why does it behave differently depending on if the identifier type is a class or a struct even when the == and hash functions are the same? Or even the === function is overridden for classes so that it acts more like a value type?

Example:

```
import UIKit

public class DebugViewController: UIViewController {

    typealias SectionType = IntWrapper
    typealias ItemType = IntWrapper
    
    public class IntWrapper: Hashable {
        public static func == (lhs: DebugViewController.IntWrapper, rhs: DebugViewController.IntWrapper) -> Bool {
            lhs.number == rhs.number
        }
        public static func === (lhs: DebugViewController.IntWrapper, rhs: DebugViewController.IntWrapper) -> Bool {
            lhs.number == rhs.number
        }
        public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(number)
        }
        var number: Int
        
        init(number: Int) {
            self.number = number
        }
    }
    
    private var dataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<SectionType, ItemType>!
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
        
        dataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<SectionType, ItemType>(tableView: tableView) { (tableView, indexPath, item) -> UITableViewCell? in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DefaultCell")!
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(item.number)"
            return cell
        }
        
        apply()
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        apply()
    }
    
    func apply() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<SectionType, ItemType>()
        
        let sections = [IntWrapper(number: 0)]
        let items = [IntWrapper(number: 1)]
        snapshot.appendSections(sections)
        sections.forEach { snapshot.appendItems( items, toSection: $0) }
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}
```

If `IntWrapper` is a struct the table view does nothing when `apply()` is called (`apply()` essentially loads in the same data) For me, this is the expected behavior.

If `IntWrapper` is a class the table view reloads when apply() is called. Also, the `hash()` and == functions are NOT even called.

I don't think this can be answered unless someone has access to the source (hint, hint) or unless I made some mistake in my example.

Comment: Did you ever figure out? I've been stuck 2 days trying to figure this out

Comment: @gmogames I just stick to using `struct`s whenever possible. If the data can be identical for two structs when I add an `let id: UUID` to each struct so that they are always unique. If you get two structs with the same data the app will crash. If the data needs to be updated I create a new struct with the same id but change the values and add that to the new snapshot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some investigation I found that `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` uses `NSOrderedSet` under the hood. Before passing the array of identifiers to the ordered set it is being converted to an array of Objective-C objects (by means of `Swift._bridgeAnythingToObjectiveC<τ_0_0>(τ_0_0) -> Swift.AnyObject` function). Because Swift and Objective-C classes share [same memory layout](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-07-18-exploring-swift-memory-layout.html) they are passed as is. `NSOrderedSet` then relies on the `hash` and `isEqual:` Objective-C methods instead of `Hashable`, and Swift provides default implementations for those same as for `NSObject` even when a class is not subclassed from `NSObject`, but there's no forwarding calls to `Hashable` (only the other way round).

That said, the only correct way of using classes in diffable data sources is to subclass them from `NSObject` or at least implement `hash()` and `isEqual(_:)` methods with `@objc` annotation.

Comment: Very interesting, but how does it answer the question that was actually asked?

Comment: @matt I extended the answer. `NSObjects`'s implementation of `Hashable` is forwarding to `hash` and `isEqual:` but not the other way round.

Comment: @NickolayTarbayev Excellent answer, thank you very much. I'm interested in how you did your investigation.

Comment: @BryanBryce I just set a couple of breakpoints for the struct items case and dug through the assembler code in the call stack looking for some meaningful symbols. There I found the `NSOrederedSet` and `_bridgeAnythingToObjectiveC` function. Then I verified my assumption by implementing Obj-C methods in a Swift class used as an item.