Applying a snapshot of equal model data still results in collection cells reloading
I have a subscription that fires too often causing my code to call snapshot.apply() way more than is necessary. And while I agree I should work to avoid this the fact that all the cells regenerate suggests to me that I am fundamentally misusing my UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource in some way.
I checked and the only code doing calls to the data source is the following
typealias DataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, CellModel>
typealias Snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, CellModel>

func setupDataSource() -> DataSource {
    let dataSource = DataSource(
        collectionView: collectionView,
        cellProvider: { collectionView, indexPath, model ->
          UICollectionViewCell? in
          let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: "CollabPageCollectionViewCell",
            for: indexPath) as? CollabPageCollectionViewCell
          cell?.pageModel = model
          return cell
      })
    return dataSource
}
func callAfterUpdatingCollectionModels() {
    if memory.count == collectionPages.count {
        for i in 0..<memory.count {
            if memory[i] != collectionModels[i] {
                print("EQUATABLE FAIL AT \(i)")
            }
            if memory[i].hashValue != collectionModels[i].hashValue {
                print("EQUATABLE FAIL AT \(i)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("This print should only be seen once ")
    }
    memory = collectionModels
    guard self.collectionView.dataSource != nil else { return }

    var snapshot = Snapshot()
    snapshot.appendSections([.main])
    snapshot.appendItems(collectionModels)

    self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
}
onOverZealousModelSubscription {
   // Rebuild collectionModels to be exactly the same thing it used to be
   callAfterUpdatingCollectionModels()
}

And then the model object here
class CellModel: Hashable, Equatable, ObservableObject  {
    static func == (lhs: CellModel, rhs: CellModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.aspect == rhs.aspect && lhs.delegate === rhs.delegate && lhs.shouldBeHighlighted == rhs.shouldBeHighlighted
    }

    let id: UUID
    let aspect: CGFloat
    private(set) weak var delegate: CellModelDelegate?
    @Published var shouldBeHighlighted: Bool

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        id.hash(into: &hasher)
        aspect.hash(into: &hasher)
        shouldBeHighlighted.hash(into: &hasher)
    }
}

So what gives? To me I have verified the hashes and count of all model objects are equal. The backtrace of the dequeueReusableCell verifies its coming from the self.dataSource.apply yet STILL these cells are all trying to update.
I did create a minimum reproducible case of this but there is no good way to upload that project here that I know of.

Figured it out after some time. Here's the deal. Because the implementation of this UIDiffableDataSource implementing Equatable and Hashable is ineffective even though the documentation does not suggest such.
Making this object implement NSObject and exposing equatable and hashable to objective c got this working. This is detailed more in an answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69994675/3833632
